# How to view corresponding SQL Server tables From NAV

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-dynamics, navision

I have to extract data from Microsoft Dynamics NAV and save it as CSV files. And I am trying to do it by creating an SSIS package.

Is there a way I can find the corresponding SQL table to a NAV table?

I remember one of the developers using a tool called 'Zoom' to view the tables. I do have access to Zoom but not sure how to find the underlying SQL table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables on SQL server named the same as in Nav plus two things:

1. Not allowed characters are replaced with underscore. So "G/L entry" will become "G_L Entry"
2. If table exist for each company then company name with dollar sign as separator is added before table name. Like this "Cronus$G_L Entry".

Comment: You can grab the identifiers (the character which NAV will convert to Underscore) from File -> Database -> Alter -> Integration